# Teamcity does not startup with Debians tomcat7 package

Tags: tomcat, teamcity

I am currently struggling with the setup of TeamCity on Tomcat7:

> Unable to initialize logs. The logs directories are not accessible for writing.
>   TeamCity server process does not have enough permissions to write into the log files under the directory:
>   /var/lib/tomcat7/../logs
>   Please fix permissions and restart TeamCity. You can read more about TeamCity logs in documentation.

When I installed Tomcat manually by downloading the apache-tomcat*.tar.gz file and started up the servlet container, everything worked fine. Nevertheless I decided to use the tomcat7 package provided by Debian and to install it via:

```
apt-get install tomcat7
```

Regretfully TeamCity seems to have problems with the Debian package version and does not start up anymore.

What are the necessary step to run TeamCity in this tomcat7 version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set logs directory to some location, that TeamCity will be able to write to. There is [the documentation section](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/TeamCity+Server+Logs#TeamCityServerLogs-GeneralLoggingConfiguration) that describes general logging configuration.

**EDIT**

Use system property `-Dteamcity_logs=../logs/` with desired logs directory

Comment: "By default TeamCity searches for log4j configuration in ../conf/teamcity-server-log4j.xml". Afaik this configuration folder is created during the first start up of TeamCity. Nevertheless it does not get this far because it immediately stop with the given message posted above.

Comment: The only way of achieving this would be to set an environment variable like for example TEAMCITY_HOME but I already tried that and it had no impact.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem and TeamCity started without any error.